# System events capture in Mac

Tags: macos, events

Please share your idea or approach for capturing a system generated event in a Macintosh apple device.
Events like

- Pressing Esc key .
- Pressing Command + Tab .
- When system goes to sleep .
- When screen saver starts in the system .
- When restart/shutdown happens .

Please share the possible ways for doing this kind of stuff..

Comment: As it stands this is too broad. Do you want to do this in an Objective C program or something else?

Comment: I am searching a way by using Java script or Java if possible . Other wise any approach

Comment: hey greg-449 any solutions ?